# Programmatically add custom layouts

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a card layout which can be used multiple times in multiple activities.

My custom_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="#000000">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    tools:padding="15dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to include this in an activity, so I wrote a Card class and added methods to change the text and other view values.

CustomCard.java

```
public class CustomCard extends RelativeLayout{

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private View mView;
    private ImageView mCardImg;
    private TextView mCardTitle;
    private TextView mCardDescription;

    public CustomCard(Context context){
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_card, this, true);

    }

    // setters of texts and other view elements
}
```

I am struggling with rendering this card inside any activity. I have created the object of customCard inside the activity, do I need to write something else also?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating this CustomCard or using in XML ?

Comment: I am dynamically creating object of CustomCard which uses the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're not attaching your newly created card to any of the layouts in your Activity.

Let's say the root layout of your activity is a `LinearLayout` with the id `R.id.activity_main`, then you can create a new card and add it to your activity with

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

CustomCard card = new CustomCard(this);

layout.addView(card);
```

Comment: I was trying to add multiple cards by 

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            CustomCard card = new CustomCard(getApplicationContext());
            mCurrentLayout.addView(card);
        }
but its creating just 1 card

Comment: Maybe you're only seeing one card on the UI because your cards have both width and height of `match_parent`, which in this case is probably the size of your whole Activity layout. Try using `wrap_content` or a fixed size for the height and width instead.

Comment: Also the background color of layout is not what I have given. Any ideas on this?

Comment: If you want to color the whole card's background, you can use the `app:cardBackgroundColor` attribute from XML.

Answer (score 0):

You did  not added your inflated view into CustomCard:

see below init method :

```
public void init(){
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dwsdf, this, true);
//Add below line into your code
addView(mView);
}
```

Comment: Its creating a crash with this exception
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 16110580 bytes

Comment: post your java code where you have create Customlayout.

Comment: try by passing false in last parameter of inflate method.

Comment: Just creating an object of CustomCard inside an activity

Comment: with false value in ,my code its working . Also have you added your CustomLayout to your Activity.

Comment: False solved the crash but still has the rendering issue, anyways the other answer solved the rendering, thanks for your time